# VB WebBrowser Span Access

Tags: vb.net

```
<div id="Fruits" class="item">
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td class="header">Category</td>
<td class="text">
<span id="aaaaa" class="Name"><a href="" rel="category tag">Apple</a></span>

<span id="bbbbb" class="Name"><a href="" rel="category tag">Orange</a></span>

<span id="ccccc" class="Name"><a href="" rel="category tag">Melon</a></span>

<span id="ddddd" class="Name"><a href="" rel="category tag">Banana</a></span>

<span id="ddddd" class="Name"><a href="" rel="category tag">Watermelon</a></span>

<td class="icon"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

I would like to obtain the "Apple", "Orange", "Melon", "Banana", "Watermelon" via VB WebBrowser, however when i use the code

```
WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("Fruits").GetAttribute("innerText")
```

I got AppleOrangeMelonBananaWatermelon

Is it possible to obtain like separately or they have a comma in between

Apple,Orange,Melon,Banana,Watermelon

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an alternative, using the xPath syntax. I don't know if you can use the xPath with the object "webBrowser" but this is a complete alternative. I hope can this help you.

```
Private Sub stackOverflowExample()

    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim lnk As String = "http://www.example.com"

    Try

        Dim html = client.DownloadString(lnk)
        Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html)

        For Each node As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@id='fruits']")
            ' get inner html ---> node.InnerHtml
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```